# Bootstrap and Boilerplate IE9 Demo page broken?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

Well, I was trying to test bootstrap and boilerplate from http://www.initializr.com/
Non of their templates with demo works in my IE9? Shouldn't it be working?

Or do I need to do extra modifications?

Win7 IE9 standard(even reset)
Screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg9611rxe4hfbeo/initilizr_try.jpg

Comment: what kinda issues you are facing , if you can paste the respectove codes and screenshots .. would help us help you better.

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot from IE9.

Comment: Do you get any error message or popup .. have you changed any settings of IE9

Answer (score 0):

Check the screenshot , its working fine on my comp.

[image: IE9 screenshot working perfectly]

[image: Select IE9 instead of IE9 compatability - check screenshot]

Comment: Thats so strange! What can be wrong with my IE9? :( I've done a reset.
Why does it go in to compability mode?

Comment: strangely on your screenshot its all messed up as if something kicked the shit outta that page ...

Comment: can you press F12 and see wat is selected in browser option .. is it IE9 standard or IE9 compatibility mode

Comment: This is a swedish version of IE9, it might be that? Yeah haha Shail, but when you think of it, IE would need a real beating...

Comment: HEHE .. check the screenshot and change the IE9 compability mode to IE9 and it will work for sure

Comment: do you have teamviewer , so that I can take a look

Comment: That is very kind, but cant do that sorry.